# C# IoC Container that scans the bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, mono, ioc-container, auto-registration

I am looking for an IoC container that scans all types in all assemblies within the bin folder AND is compatible with mono.

I used to use LightCore, which took a little configuration to declare the implementation of a specific interface, and then automagically resolves it, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with mono...

I have tried TinyIoC too, but that one only scans types within referenced assemblies, and my problem is that the assembly that contains the implementation cannot be referenced by my other project that needs to resolve it (circular reference issue).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the circular reference issue, which will take care of two problems.

Comment: I agree with D Stanley, but after you fix that you may want to head over to [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) with this question.

Comment: Well, unless there's something I'm missing (and I'm happy to hear about it if that's the case), I don't think I need to change anything. My main entities and business logic in assembly A, and data access stuff in assembly B. Assembly B references A to know about the types, then A cannot have a ref to B, as that would cause the circular ref issue. But using DI means that at any time, I can change assembly B (which currently uses NHibernate) for assembly C (which could use EntityFramework for example), change the config and have the whole thing work without recompiling the main project.

Comment: This is silly. You don't need auto-scanning support; it can be easily write this yourself. Take a look at [this](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios&referringTitle=Documentation#Plugins) for instance.

Comment: You're right, it is silly, I was just wondering if there was anything out of the box, but thanks for this, I will try to implement it myself :)